# mysql update statement path links adjustment

Tags: mysql

I got table smile need to update smilepath  ( mass update ) im using  this

```
 UPDATE `smilie` SET `smiliepath` = 'http://newpathhere.com/smilies/smile.gif' WHERE `smilieid` =1;
```

ive to issues , 
need to mass update to all paths , i believe i can use where smileid > 1 not quite sure
2nd issue in old path its looks like http://oldpath.com/icons/smile.gif 
so i need to replace only " http://oldpath.com/icons " and keep end file 
any clue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql REPLACE function to do this:

```
UPDATE `smilie` SET `smiliepath` = REPLACE(smiliepath,' http://oldpath.com/icons/','http://newpathhere.com/smilies/') WHERE `smilieid` >1;
```